# how to create a project from a template within youtrack with external hub integration?

Tags: youtrack, jetbrains-hub

I am experimenting with latest hub and youtrack on a linux machine,
I installed latest versions (2019.2 and 2019.1 respectively) and enabled the hub integration in youtrack. (not using https for the moment, old plain http is used)

What happened is this:

1. When I try to create a project i am always switched to Hub (is this correct? i did not find anything on JetBrains docs)
2. If I create a project from the hub interface and then click on the left panel to add a "Youtrack service" then i am offered the option to create only "default, scrum and kanban" projects that are the standard ones provided by JetBRains, however if i had already created a project and saved as template that project is not offered to me as an option to be the base of the new one.
3. If i use youtrack with the internal hub, all works as expected and the template projects are available as a starting point for new projects.

This happens as well with older versions (2018.4) of hub and youtrack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I recall this is bug in Hub yet to be fixed.

1. It seems correct, as with an external Hub installed projects are always created from there

2-3. There's known issue with that: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JPS-9928